# Check if TAG is applied to contact or not - InfusionSoft Campaign

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am using InfusionSoft for marketing purpose.

Here is a Campaign. For just to explain.

In "`Thanking the Happy Customer`" email, I send a link to my site to fill up a form and I add a TAG `Testimonial Submitted` to the contact (and there is another campaign running against '`Testimonial Submitted`' tag).

What I want to do is that I want to send "`Offer Coupon`" Email to only those contacts who does not have '`Testimonial Submitted`' TAG applied to it. If that TAG is applied, do not send `odder coupon` Email

How to implement this check?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this on the Campaign level instead of the Sequence level. So put "Offer Coupon" and "Coupon Reminder" in a separate sequence called "Coupon Sequence"

Then, create another sequence that you want to send if the contact does have the "Testimonial Submitted" tag. This sequence can be empty if you don't want to send anything to them. Draw an arrow from the sequence containing the "Thanking the Happy Customer" e-mail to each of the 2 new sequences. When you draw the arrow to both of them, a decision node will appear that you can open up and set rules in.